# Reversed Linked List not showing the last element

Tags: list, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Im implementing a reversed sorted Linked list. If I print the ascending version of this linked list,it works fine but printing the reversed list does chops off the last element (last input).

```
private class Node {

    private T data;
    private Node next;

    private Node(T data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = null;
    }

    private Node(T data, Node next) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }

    private Node() {
        this.data = null;
        this.next = null;
    }

}
```

```
    public T reverseList() {
        if (head == null || head.next == null) { //if theres only 1 data to display,dont proceed to reverse
            return head.data;                    
        }
    
        Node prev = null;
        Node current = head;
        Node next = null;
        while (current != null) {
            next = current.next;
            current.next = prev;
            prev = current;
            current = next;
        }
        return prev.data;
    }
```

> Input : 3,1,2
> Sorted Ascending output: 1,2,3
> Sorted Reversed output: 3,1,3

As you can see, if I print the reversed list more than 3 times, it repeats itself like `3,1,3,1,3,1...`
Please forgive me if this question/code is unclear, Im new to this platform.

Comment: How are you producing that output? I don't see how that could happen. Can you add the code that we can run so to see this output?

Comment: I see two problems with `reverseList` right now. In the initial conditional, you return `head.data` if `head == null`. That's a problem. Also, at the end of `reverseList` you are returning `prev.data` while you should return `prev` itself as the head node of the reversed linked list. As @trincot said, we need to see the rest of the code, because you are accessing the head of the reversed list from somewhere else and one can't tell your specific problem from this part of the code.